# How to change the parent Domain Name in Multisites Project?

Tags: multisite, urls, domain

I have a multisite project. And then i want to change the parent domain name now. It is currently as:

Parent:

```
www.site1.com
```

Multisites:

```
www.oldsite.com/abc
www.oldsite.com/def
```

So how can i change the parent domain `oldsite.com` into `newsite.com` ?
So the multisites will be automatically affected as:

```
www.newsite.com/abc
www.newsite.com/def
```

How can i get it?

Comment: When [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11711597/1287812), it's nice to [cross-link them](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/214/12615)...

Answer (score 1):

this is a complex task (and takes even longer if you have many subsites already).

**THINGS TO THINK ABOUT**
Basically allow yourself 48 hours and start by making a list of all things that will be affected such as:
- Adwords
- Google Webmaster Tools
- Google Analytics
- PageRank
- Twitter / Facebook & losing all the social sharing stats
- How many domains to change
- DNS settings / cpanel settings
- 301 redirect everything

**How many Subsites do you have?**
You will need to make database table changes for every subsite  ... manually ... 
you need to change wp_*siteid*_options for each site

**Don't rely on search and replace for oldsite.com -> newsite.com**
First reason is that your web host may have directory structure like `/www/public_html/oldsite.com/`

So any linked images or files will break if you just do a search & replace.

**wp blogs**
WordPress Multisite has this table you'll need to check and make changes to it.

**.htaccess**
You'll need to setup a 301 redirect for oldsite.com -> newsite.com

See also http://wordpress.damien.co/2012/05/change-your-wordpress-multi-site-domain-url/

Comment: Serialized data must be replaced with a proper tool, like [Search Replace DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB). With BackupBuddy 2, I had to run this for finishing the export/import. Btw, I always do a local mirror of my Multisites with BB without much fuss.